# How to add text to an image Dinamic content

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image, wordpress-rest-api

I need to make a website like https://www.wonderbly.com/ in wordpress, the idea of the page is that a kid put his name and choose a template and character, the web generates a book with that template, character and the name of the kid is around the book

Is there a plugin of wordpress to make that dinamic content? or how can I code this? I'm making this in wordpress to make it easier for the administrator of the foundation to manage

I'm donating the website to a foundation for kids with cancer and think is a good idea, but obviously cant use wonderbly because it's suppoused to be free and I'm donating just my time making this for them

Comment: A noble cause @Daniel, good luck with your efforts. I don\t beleive you will find a ready made plugin for this however. You will need to google wordpress 'custom templates' and 'shortcodes' which I think will help you acheve this. It should not be too tricky, but will certainly be a custom solution.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library, tutorial, book, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. If you cannot find a resource that does what you want it to, then you'll need to write your own.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Good Luck.
You can create a Plugin for this website. and also check this wp plugin [logaster](https://wordpress.org/plugins/logaster-logo-generator/).
thanks for your time.